# Calculating volume by disc integration

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the volume $V$ of the object created when the area formed by the lines $$y=x$$ $$y = 2-x^2$$ $$0 \le y \le 2$$ is rotated around the $y$-axis?

It says that the answer is $\dfrac{5\pi}{6}$.

Here are the two things that I tried:

$$V = \pi \int_{0}^{2} 2-y-y^2 \,dy$$

$$V_1 = \pi \int_{0}^{1} 1-y^2 \,dy$$

$$V_2 = \pi \int_{1}^{2} 2-y-1 \, dy$$

$$V= V_1 + V_2$$

I don't see what's wrong with either of them to be honest yet they both give different answers none of which are correct.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps there is another constraint for the area like the y-axis, or x-axis?

Comment: Not sure if it helps but I added to my post a picture of the area that I believe you're supposed to integrate.

Comment: Are you sure the interval is $[0,2]$?

Comment: Because intersection of these curves is at $(1,1)$

Comment: It also includes the portion above the intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it is easier to do the shell method. break the region into thin strips of width $dx$ and length $(2-x^2) - x.$  if you rotate about the $y$-axis, then you cylindrical shell of radius $x.$  putting all these together, we have $$V = 2\pi\int_0^1 x\left(2-x^2 - x\right)\, dx $$

if you insist on the disk method, then break it into two solids:

(a)   $0\le y \le 1,$ have a cone of height $1$ and base radius $1.$ therefore the volume is $V_1=\frac13\pi.$

(b) $1 \le y \le 2.$ the volume is $$V_2 = \pi\int_1^2 x^2 \, dy = \pi\int_1^2(2-y)\, dy  $$